# Format Curly Braces on End Previous Line in C++ VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, format, clang-format, curly-braces

Currently, I have the setting `"C_Cpp.clang_format_formatOnSave"` set to `true`.

This format's my code when I save my C++ file. But the format results in curly braces on new lines rather than on the same line.

**Current C++ VSCode Formatted**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // ...
}
```

**What I Want C++ VSCode Formatted Code to Look Like**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // ...  }
```

**How can I make curly braces in C++ format on end of the previous line in Visual Studio Code?**

**Not** the same question as [Format Curly Braces on Same Line in C++ VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111834/format-curly-braces-on-same-line-in-c-vscode).

Comment: Getting the opening curly brace at the end of the `for` line shouldn't be a problem but you also show that the closing brace should be at the end  of the last line in the brace enclosed block. I doubt there's a `clang-format` setting for that since it's a rather unconventional place to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Artistic Style](https://astyle.sourceforge.net/) [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chiehyu.vscode-astyle):

```
Name: Astyle
Id: chiehyu.vscode-astyle
Description: Format C/C++/Obj-C/C#/Java code with Astyle in VSCode
Version: 0.9.0
Publisher: Chieh Yu
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chiehyu.vscode-astyle
```

which has [Python/Lisp indenting format](https://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_style=lisp) feature:

[image: --style=lisp / --style=python / -A12]

Astyle found from [@mmj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694360/mmj)'s [comment to 'How to make clang-format keep closing braces on same line'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220297/how-to-make-clang-format-keep-closing-braces-on-same-line#comment63866571_38221761).