# Astyle format a cpp2 file automatically in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, astyle, cppfront

Using Astyle extension with VS Code. I can format a [cpp2](https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront) file with Ctrl+Shift+I.

How can I have the formatting happen automatically at other times such as a text paste or file save?

Installed:

- [C/C++ Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack)
- [cpp2 (cppfront) Syntax Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=elazarcoh.cpp2-syntax)
- [Astyle extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366027/format-curly-braces-on-end-previous-line-in-c-vscode/76681630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) in `settings.json` add:

```
"[cpp2]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "chiehyu.vscode-astyle",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
},
```

which applies the formatting when the file is saved.